# Range.Find.Execute - Forward only misbehave

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I'm using the .Net libraries for Microsoft Word 2010 interoping

```
Word.Document doc = wb.Documents[1];
Word.Range range = doc.Range();

range.Find.Forward = true;
range.Find.Execute("HELLO");

MessageBox.Show("Start " + range.Start.ToString());
MessageBox.Show("End " + range.End.ToString());

//make sure it won't even look back
range.Start = range.End;

range.Find.Execute("HELLO");

MessageBox.Show("Start " + range.Start.ToString());
MessageBox.Show("End " + range.End.ToString());
```

if the document has more than one "HELLO" in it, the range that is returned just ignores it, it keeps finding the same string, I keep getting the same range.Start and range.End values over and over again. what am i missing here ?

Comment: This code won't compile (there's no` Forward` on `Range`, missing semi-colons).  I've fixed it up and run it and I can't reproduce - I get different starts and ends if `Hello` is in the document more than once.

Comment: Edited. Odd, is there anything that can pop to your mind as to why this just won't go forward ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I isolated the problem and it seem to happen **only when there's special characters in the word document, particularity if text is contained inside a custom table**. on normal plain documents it works fine.

I ended up sampling the range.Start value after each search, if it was the same as the prior one, I increase it's start range by + 1 and then re-search.

This is done again and again and although it adds a few more searches it's quite stable.

```
while (range.text.Contains("HELLO"))
{
    range.Find.Execute("HELLO");

    while ((range.Start < intLastFoundRangeStartValue) && (range.Find.Found))
    {
        range.Start += intAddToRangeStartValue;
        intAddToRangeStartValue++;

        range.Find.Execute("HELLO");
    }
}
...
```

In addition as a by-product it relives me from the need to add a counter to the loop.